# How to add pairs of elements in Python set comprehension depending on boolean statement?

Tags: python, set, set-comprehension

I have a frozenset of three elements F = {v0,v1,v2} and a set of frozensets of two elements, i.e., E = {e0,e1,e2,...} where each ei=frozenset({x,y}). I want to find the following set

S = {frozenset({a,b}) : a,b in E, a and b each contain distinct elements of F, and a and b share an element}.

ex: a contains v0, b contains v1, and a and b both contain v7 (some arbitrary value not in F) means frozenset({a,b}) is in S.

Can I do this with a one line set comprehension?

For context, I am trying to write a script to refine an octahedron triangulation as shown in the picture:

[image: algorithm]

the set S I'm after would be the green text.

So far I have the following:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

### Initial octahedron ###

Vertices = [ [0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [-1,0,0], [0,-1,0], [0,0,-1] ]
Edges = { frozenset({0,1}), frozenset({0,2}), frozenset({0,3}), frozenset({0,4}),
          frozenset({1,2}), frozenset({2,3}), frozenset({3,4}), frozenset({1,4}),
          frozenset({1,5}), frozenset({2,5}), frozenset({3,5}), frozenset({4,5}) }
Faces = { frozenset({0,1,2}), frozenset({0,2,3}), frozenset({0,3,4}), frozenset({0,1,4}),
          frozenset({1,2,5}), frozenset({2,3,5}), frozenset({3,4,5}), frozenset({1,4,5}) }

### New set of vertices, edges, and faces ###

counter=5

newVertices=set()
newEdges=set()
newFaces=set()

for edge in Edges: # adding elements of newVertices and newEdges
    counter=counter+1
    newVertices.add(counter)
    for vertex in edge:
        newEdges.add(frozenset({vertex,counter}))
```

Comment: Sample data for understanding and testing would be good.

Comment: What does *"a and b each contain distinct elements of F"* mean? That doesn't seem true for your example, where a and b each both contain only *one* element of F.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes they each contain one element of F but those respective elements are distinct

Comment: Before you worry about a one-liner, can you give us what you think the code would look like?  Why do you care if it's a one-liner or not?

Comment: If I set `F = {6, 7, 8}` in the accepted answer's example, what should the result be?

Comment: @FrankYellin My first attempt was the following: `F = {1, 2, 3}
E = {frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([2, 3]), frozenset([3, 4]), frozenset([1, 4]), frozenset([2,6]), frozenset([10,11])}

I={e for e in E if len(e.intersection(F))==1}
S=set()
for i in I:
    for j in I:
        if len(F.intersection(i.intersection(j)))==1:
            continue
        else:
            if len(i.intersection(j))==1:
                S.add((i,j))
print(S)`

Comment: @KellyBundy the accepted answer didn't quite give me the set S but it gave me enough to work with to modify it to what I need. Specifically the following: `F = {1, 2, 3}
E = {frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([2, 3]), frozenset([3, 4]), frozenset([1, 4]), frozenset([2,6]), frozenset([10,11])}

print({(a, b) for a, b in combinations({s for s in E if len(s.intersection(F))==1}, 2) if (a & b) and (len(a.intersection(b))==1)})` I know a lot of information about the sets F and E so that's why I'm using `len()` in my boolean tests

Comment: So you accepted a wrong answer?

Comment: @KellyBundy I wouldn't say it's wrong, they gave me exactly what I was searching for; a one-line set/list comprehension that performs a boolean test with two elements of E and adds those elements to S if the test is passed. Just a matter of changing the boolean statements a bit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IIUC you can do:

```py
from itertools import combinations

F = {1, 2, 3}
E = {frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([2, 3]), frozenset([3, 4]), frozenset([3, 5])}

print([(a, b) for a, b in combinations({s for s in E if s - F}, 2) if a & b])
```

Prints:

```py
[(frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({3, 5}))]
```

---

Explanation:

With:

```py
F = {1, 2, 3}
E = {frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([2, 3]), frozenset([3, 4]), frozenset([3, 5])}
```

I'm trying to find combination of two frozensets from set `E` that share common element **and** have some element distinct from elements in `F`

Comment: If you need to start an answer with "IIUC", please don't attempt to write one. Questions that lack clarity are unsuitable for the site until clarified, and should be closed and not answered. Please read [answer] for details.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Happy New Year Karl! :)